# Implement expandalbelistview with no child

Tags: android, listview, drop-down-menu

how to implement expandalbelistview with not any child
I am new in android I want to implement and expandalbelistview in which some groups have children and some have none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This
It works for me

```
mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.grouplist);

    groupCollection = new LinkedHashMap<>();


    List<String> newsCategories = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> nullcats = new ArrayList<>();
    nullcats.add(null);

    ArrayList<Categories> categories1 = new ArrayList<>();
//dataSource is my DBOpen helper class
    categories1 = dataSource.findAllCategories();
    if (categories1 != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < categories1.size(); i++) {
            newsCategories.add(categories1.get(i).getCatagory_name_en());
        }
    } else {
        newsCategories.add(null);
    }

    groupCollection.put(groupList.get(0), nullcats);
    groupCollection.put(groupList.get(1), newsCategories);


        expandableListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, groupList, groupCollection);
        mExpandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
```